# Quickblox users sort

Tags: sorting, quickblox

Can users be sorted in Paged Requests similar to Custom Objects when using Quickblox?

For example, I am hoping to be able to sort users by last requests. The idea is that the user can find all users who say like "dogs" and then get a list of the users who have used the app most recently first.

Using Custom objects, I can use sort_asc=field_name and sort_desc=field_name parameters. I have looked through the documentation and have failed to find anything suggesting that this is possible for users.

Am I missing something, or does anyone have a suggestion on how I should go about this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use **order** parameter in GET Users query

http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Sort

For example, you would like to sort users by **last_request_at** field:

```
https://api.quickblox.com/users.xml?order=asc%20date%20last_request_at
```

iOS SDK way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *filters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
filters[@"order"] = @"desc date last_request_at";
// filters[@"filter[]"] = @"number id in 1,3,4";
[QBUsers usersWithExtendedRequest:filters delegate:self];
```

Comment: Ok, I do not have enough reputation to up vote this - Sorry. But thank you very much. I do not know how I missed that section in your link. I read it so many times.

Thank you again and I quickblox is an amazing service!

Comment: Ok, Sorry, I am actually not sure how to get this to work when making a request. For example, when using this with a GET query, if I'm in Objective C, I currently:PagedRequest *request = [[PagedRequest alloc] init];request.perPage = pageSize;request.page = page; [QBUsers usersWithIDs:@"1" pagedRequest:getRequest delegate:self];

How do I actually apply the order? With Custom Objects, I can use an extended request, but that doesn't work for users?

Comment: Do you need it for this query with IDs?

Comment: I would like to be able to use it with IDs. - I have a custom object that stores additional fields about the user. I query those custom objects to find user IDs. Then I use the above query to get the users related to the IDs using pagination.- This is a for a social networking app where you want to find individuals based on the fields of the custom object and then chat with them. Thus, I would like to query for the users online most recently because they will be most likely to reply quickly. --- Is this possible? and how does the query currently decided which users to GET first without sort?

Comment: or, do you have a better way to do what I am trying to do? --Again, thank you for taking the time to answer these questions and Quickblox is an amazing service all the more because you offer help like this.

Comment: Updated answer - added iOS example

Comment: Awesome - how did I not know that I could use extendedRequests with users? Thank you and if I could I would upvote!

Comment: Use at least all params you can find here http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Retrieve_all_Users_for_current_account   in Params, Filters, Sort tables

Comment: I saw the updated SDK yesterday. You are awesome Igor - Thanks!